# How To Embed Google Reviews Into HTML or PHP Using Google Places API

Tags: php, html, json, google-places-api, google-reviews

I want to display 3-5 (read-only) Google reviews on a webpage.  Google's Developer Support has suggested I use the Places API instead of the My Business API to display read-only reviews.

I have my place-id and Google Places API key to put into the following URL.  If I put this URL into the browser, it returns the JSON list of reviews.  However, I can't figure out how to embed these reviews into my HTML or PHP on the webpage.

How can I get the JSON output from the following URL to embed or display within the HTML or PHP of my site?

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=[my-place-id]&fields=rating,review&key=[my-api-key]"></script>
```

How do you embed the JSON output of an external script within HTML or PHP?